# Is it possible to tag post comments and replies via the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

When responding to a post on a page using the API, is it possible to attach a tag to the comment or comment reply?

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog post it looks possible.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/new-apis-for-comment-replies/

And text_tags looks like it may be the answer.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment